# Why are most complex analysis theorems about functions on open set?

Tags: complex-analysis

This could be a stupid question but are most theorems in complex analysis including open maps because it allows for holomorphic (and hence analytic) functions to ehibit certain properties? Things like the maximum modulus principle comes to mind and many results follow from it. Am I correct in thinking that open sets allow for these properties to occur and this is why a set is often assumed open?

Comment: I don't know that much complex analysis to confirm that most of the theorems are about that, but certainly we are interested in complex-differentiable functions. Differentiability is (usually, I imagine there are generalizations) defined for a function with an open domain.

Comment: @qualcuno I think there is a lot of truth in that as for a function to be holomorphic at a point we require for it to be differentiable from all directions (i.e. an open circle with radius $\epsilon$ centered at the point)

Comment: A function on a subset $S$ of $\mathbf C$ is *defined* to be analytic on $S$ if it is the restriction to $S$ of an analytic function on an open set containing $S$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many properties in complex analysis deal with local properties, i.e. properties that hold in an open neighbourhood around any $z$. The statements usually go like this:

Let $f$ be a holomorphic function defined on an open set $U$ such that... Then

$$\forall z_0 \in U: \exists\epsilon>0:\forall z\in \mathbb C, |z-z_0|<\epsilon:\dots $$

A statement starting like that is only possible if $U$ is open.